# Couldnot create an event in civicrm 4.7.20

Tags: civievent

Whenever I try creating a new event, I am facing " The page not working" error with wordpress and "The site can't be reached" error in Drupal. Not sure what is the issue.  Running CiviCRM 4.7.20
my problem seems the server is not sending any response for this request to create event

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are on 4.7.19, make sure you apply https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10325 for it to work

Comment: I am on 4.7.20 I think the same should work. Isn't it?

Comment: this is the first time I am using civiCRM. I assume all I need to do is implement the code change in the specific file and restart the services. I tried that. I am seeing the same error. Moreover  the fix seems to be for an issue unable to list all the events , however my problem seems the server is not sending any response for this request.

Comment: Even the source code in my setup looks much different than the source code and fix given in the above github link.

Comment: Maybe you could confirm for us what 'is' working? Can you create Contacts, Contribution Pages, Relationships?

Comment: are you running on php version > 7.

Comment: Everything else works like search/creating contacts/ groups/importing/ etc. running PHP 5.6.25

Comment: Are you running CiviCRM on your Windows system, or in a virtual machine?

Comment: Windows pc, WordPress. Drupal in both issues are seen

Comment: make sure you also check for errors in php log file.

Comment: Could this be possible because CRON not running?

Answer (score 1):

As Jitendra says, this could be a bug that has already been resolved. If not, you may need to dig in to your ConfigAndLog to see more errors.

Comment: I tried checking the logs. Nothing gets caught in the log files despite enabling backtrace and debugging

Comment: I am on 4.7.20 (upgraded from 4.7.16) (Drupal 7.56), and it works OK without any patch. Are you sure you ran DB upgrade after your civicrm upgrade ?

Comment: ... could also be a .htaccess issue ?

Comment: It is a fresh installation of 4.7.20. So dB upgrade is still needed.?. What should I check in. Htaccess..?